# TypeError: can't define property "current": Object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a react component *InputField* :

```
export default function InputField({ name, type, placeholder, className }, ref) {
  return (
    <input
      name={name}
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={InputTailwindStyle}
      ref={ref}
    />
  );
}
```

and I try to put it inside another component *LoginForm* where I am using *react-hook-form* to handle my form hooks:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

(some code ... )

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

<InputField
        name='password'
        type='password'
        placeholder='Password'
        ref={register}
/>
```

but I get this error:
**TypeError: cannot define property "current": Object is not extensible**

Comment: Please show all related code to make a reproducible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), where does the `ref` in `input` comes from?

Comment: I edited my question, now you can see the first line of my component

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use [`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) for property `ref` to be valid in function component:

```
function InputField({ name, type, placeholder, className }, ref) {
  return (
    <input
      name={name}
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={`py-2 text-cTxt placeholder-gray-400 bg-transparent border-b-2 my-5 border-cBtn rounded px-2 ${className}`}
      ref={ref}
    />
  );
}

export default React.forwardRef(InputField);
```

Comment: You must use 'props' param otherwise it wont work.